# Демон не отображает требуемый контент, не смотря на статус active

Tags: python, linux, gmail, systemd

Я написал простой Python скрипт, который обращается к Gmail API раз в несколько секунд и выводит сообщение в уведомление, если оно ранее не было получено.

```py
import the required libraries
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import pickle
import os.path
import base64
import email
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import difflib
Peremenaya  = 0
import time
import notify2

# Define the SCOPES. If modifying it, delete the token.pickle file.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def getEmails():
    # Variable creds will store the user access token.
    # If no valid token found, we will create one.
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle contains the user access token.
    # Check if it exists
    if os.path.exists('/home/kali/Desktop/Python_code/token.pickle'):

        # Read the token from the file and store it in the variable creds
        with open('/home/kali/Desktop/Python_code/token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    # If credentials are not available or are invalid, ask the user to log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('/home/kali/Desktop/Python_code/credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Save the access token in token.pickle file for the next run
        with open('/home/kali/Desktop/Python_code/token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    # Connect to the Gmail API
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    # request a list of all the messages
    #result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
    # We can also pass maxResults to get any number of emails. Like this:
    result = service.users().messages().list(maxResults=1, userId='me').execute()
    messages = result.get('messages')
    # messages is a list of dictionaries where each dictionary contains a message id.
    # iterate through all the messages
    for msg in messages:
        # Get the message from its id
        txt = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg['id']).execute()
        # Use try-except to avoid any Errors
        try:
            # Get value of 'payload' from dictionary 'txt'
            payload = txt['payload']
            headers = payload['headers']

            # Look for Subject and Sender Email in the headers
            for d in headers:
                if d['name'] == 'Subject':
                    subject = d['value']
                if d['name'] == 'From':
                    sender = d['value']
            # The Body of the message is in Encrypted format. So, we have to decode it.
            # Get the data and decode it with base 64 decoder.
            parts = payload.get('parts')[0]
            data = parts['body']['data']
            data = data.replace("-","+").replace("_","/").replace("<p>","")
            decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
            # Now, the data obtained is in lxml. So, we will parse
            # it with BeautifulSoup library
            soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_data , "lxml")
            body = soup.body()
            text = soup.get_text()
            new = 'Отправитель:' + ' ' + str(sender) + "\n" + text
            global Peremenaya
            if Peremenaya == 0:
                Peremenaya = text
                print('''It's first try ''')
            # Printing the subject, sender's email and 
            if Peremenaya != text:
                #print("Subject: ", subject)
                #print("From: ", sender)
                #print("Message: ", text)
                notify2.init('foo')
                n = notify2.Notification('Новое сообщение',new)
                n.show()
                Peremenaya = text

        except:
            pass

while True:
    getEmails()
    time.sleep(6)
```

При запуске через консоль программа прекрасно работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при запуске демона любым способом ничего не происходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки демона
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: [using python-dbus](https://pypi.org/project/notify2/) — связи с dbus, видимо, не хватает.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Не могли бы вы пожалуйста описать/отправить ссылку на пример кода, где это реализуется?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Так же, насколько мне известно, строчка notify2.init() как раз это делает